# Very large retained heap size for org.jruby.RubyRegexp$RegexpCache in JRuby Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails

We have analysed a heap dump file for our application (running on Tomcat with jruby 1.7.8).

It shows us that the retained heap size is very large (439,459,128) for the class  org.jruby.RubyRegexp$RegexpCache.  This is 48% of our memory usage

Looking at the source code for that [file](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyRegexp.java) it is 3 final static object created at startup (patternCache / quotedPatternCache / preprocessedPatternCache)

This seems to be a pretty core part of JRuby.  My question is, is it normal to have such a large percentage of the heap to be dedicated to this cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it probably cached most of the Regexp objects through out the Rails/gems/user-code source ... so it might be quite huge. unless you run into a leak (out-of-memory issue) it's all fine since the actual caches are wrapped in a soft reference, that means until there's enough memory (heap size) they will be held from garbage collection but as soon as you allocate a chunk that does not fit all (or some) of those caches may get garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, we have actually tracked down the original problem - it was caused by a simple string substitution. For details: - github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2078